# Communications link failure connecting spring boot app to aws aurora

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect the spring boot application I have created locally to an aws serverless aurora database.

I have added the maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

As well as created an application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myawsclusterlink:3306/mycluster
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=0
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=90000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=90000
```

I have also created a VPC inbounds group for the db to allow incoming traffic from my IP address.

My Issue is that that when I run the app, my connection keeps failing with an error message:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I would like to know where is the problem. Is my url wrong? Have I not enabled something on aws? Is there something missing in my code?

Also, I don't really know how to test and see where the problem is coming from in this case.

Comment: It sounds like you are running Spring Boot from your local computer, is that correct? If so, did you enable the `Publicly Accessible` setting on your Aurora cluster?

Comment: I am indeed. Would that be in addition to allowing traffic from my IP adress through VPC Security Group?

Comment: Yes, if you don't select that option in the Aurora config, the cluster does not get a public IP address so you will never be able to connect from outside the VPC.

Comment: Hmm can't seem to find that option. Do you happen to know where exactly in the Aurora or VPC settings does it sit? Sorry for being a pain haha.

Comment: I just checked. It's under the Connectivity and Security settings on each database node in your cluster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing from serverless to provisioned aurora and enabling public access solved the issue